# How to get scan info from bluetooth with python? RPi3

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I want to use `bluetoothctl` with Python to get the info about all of what is scanning through `scan on` but I can not get a properly code to do it. They just show a list with the names and the address of devices that can be found.

I'm currently using BlueZ 5.47 with `sudo bluetoothctl` and I'm getting data from the sensor when I `scan on` for BLE devices in terminal window, I want to save this output in Python, how can I do this thing in Python?

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:47:AE:DD Discovering: yes
[CHG] Device 04:B3:EC:00:1E:65 RSSI: -76
[CHG] Device 04:B3:EC:00:1E:65 UUIDs: 0000fbb0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 04:B3:EC:00:1E:65 ManufacturerData Key: 0x00ac
[CHG] Device 04:B3:EC:00:1E:65 ManufacturerData Value:
  b2 00 52 01 12 17 0c 15 0e 65 1e 00 ec b3 04     ..R......e..... 
[CHG] Device 04:B3:EC:00:1E:65 AdvertisingFlags:
  06                                               .               
[CHG] Device 04:B3:EC:00:1E:65 ManufacturerData Key: 0x00ac
[CHG] Device 04:B3:EC:00:1E:65 ManufacturerData Value:
  b2 2e 52 01 12 45 0c 15 0e 65 1e 00 ec b3 04     ..R..E...e.....
```

I saw that PyBluez could help, but It seems that it will only going to give me the name and info of the available BLE Devices during `scan on`. Do you know another tool that could help? Thanks!

Comment: To write the results of `bluetoothctl scan on` in python3.7 the `check_output`, `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` or `communicate()` approaches do not work. Only with `sys.stdout` I managed to capture the process has started e.g. `10:19:45 <subprocess.Popen object at 0x71245890>` but not the output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PyBluez but if you just want to store `bluetoothctl` output you can use Python 3 [check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function like this.

```
from subprocess import check_output

ouput = check_output(['bluetoothctl'])
```

You can then parse and use it the way you want.